# Directly printing to remote CUPS/IPP server on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, cups, kerberos

I need to use Kerberos authentication when printing from my OSX machine, however, the machine itself does not have a service account in active directory, so the KDC will not issue a delegation ticket for the local CUPS installation.

I think printing could work if the printing framework would directly print to the network CUPS server (or even to the Windows print server), bypassing the local CUPS. Is it possible to setup printing so that it directly accesses the remote print server? (asking for a service ticket for that server would succeed)

Answer (score 0):

To print using a remote server in Mac OSX you create the file:
`/etc/cups/client.conf`

with the content:

```
ServerName yourserver.domain.com
```

Of course there can be issues to deal with on the server side but this is from the client's point of view.